# Python concatenate values in rows till empty cell and continue

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation, rows

I am struggling a little to do something like that:

[image]

to get this output:

[image]

The purpose of it, is to separate a sentence into 3 parts to make some manipulations after.

Any help is welcome

Comment: what is your rule of separation?

Comment: The second line of each pair gives the separation. i.e for the first two lines the separator is given by the empty word (first line) which is given in the second line

Answer (score 0):

Select from the dataframe only the second line of each pair, which is the line
containing the separator, then use `astype(str).apply(''.join...)` to restrain the word
that can be on any `value` column on the original dataframe to a single string.
Iterate over each row using `split` with the `word[i]` of the respective row, after split
reinsert the separator back on the list, and with the recently created list build the
desired dataframe.

Input used as **data.csv**

```
title,Value,Value,Value,Value,Value
Very nice blue car haha,Very,nice,,car,haha
Very nice blue car haha,,,blue,,
A beautiful green building,A,,green,building,lol
A beautiful green building,,beautiful,,,
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# second line of each pair
d1 = df[1::2]
d1 = d1.fillna("").reset_index(drop=True)

# get separators
word = d1.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)

strings = []
for i in range(len(d1.index)):
    word_split = d1.iloc[i, 0].split(word[i])
    word_split.insert(1, word[i])
    strings.append(word_split)

dn = pd.DataFrame(strings)
dn.insert(0, "title", d1["title"])
print(dn)
```

Output from **dn**

```
                        title           0          1                2
0     Very nice blue car haha  Very nice        blue         car haha
1  A beautiful green building          A   beautiful   green building
```